# Reward early editors?

Tags: discussion

Should we, say, give editors of a question 1/10 of the reputation from the question's up- or downvotes since the time of the editing until the next edit? I think it's a good way to motivate good edits.

Comment: How do you define a 'good' edit?

Comment: or motivation garbage edits just in the hope to milk some rep

Comment: @MichaelT Edits that will make an otherwise unpopular question more popular.

Comment: @SimonKuang that is impossible to quantify.  How would you determine that?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't have to. The point is that this is just a better system to reward editors who have somewhat contributed to a question.

Comment: How much rep should sawa gotten for [editing the title](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/351409/revisions) of a very popular question? Or jdias have gotten for adding a tag?

Comment: @SimonKuang but the system needs to be able to quantify what constitutes a good edit. So you can't just magically says "good edits should share rep" without a concrete idea how it would actually work.

Comment: -1. This would do nothing but encourage people to make meaningless edits in order to gain reputation. We already have an issue with robo-reviewers just approving edits without even reading in order to earn badges, and this would encourage making needless/senseless/incomplete edits in order to gain rep. There is zero merit to this idea IMO, and many reasons not to implement it.

Answer (score 11):

I think that +2 reputation (for those below the thresholds) is reward enough.  The rest of us that edit these posts are probably not doing it for rewards or glory, but to give a helping hand in getting a poorly worded question answered, or giving clarity to a poorly phrased answer.